# Controller always has ModelState.IsValid = False

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Product model:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
    public Category Category { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

Category model:

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

ProductController with ModelState.Isvalid = False

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNoc9.png)

I tried changing the code and tried different ways of foreign key.

I know this is a basic question, but I am unable to get the result. Not storing product information to the database.

Comment: Please add more code, models do not update the database. Nor do they get data. You need to look deeper into the modelstate. There is an inner exception that tells you why it hasn't validated

Comment: please look at the image i attached ProductController data is getting fetched but one field is invalid that is Category foreign key. thats why not saving to database.

Comment: Would suggest not using entity as the request body model. Use Data Transfer Object (DTO) and then map to entity model.

Comment: @Techsupport I know that, but you have to look deeper into the exception. Unfold till you find it. The modelstate always gives a reason (although tough to find).

Comment: The model state says `Category` is invalid. Maybe category is a required field but `Category` is null?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The error is purely because of validation , use [ValidateNever] before the Category , this way the property never be validated.

Comment: This is a workaround not a solution